# Exception while deploying jpa app on glassfish

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, glassfish, derby

I am using Hibernate as JPA provider and Oracle as database, but while deploying app I am getting

```
  Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:146)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:103)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1512)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:129)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientBaseDataSourceRoot.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:117)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.initConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientBaseDataSourceRoot.getConnectionX(Unknown Source)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 86 more
]]
```

this error below is my persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="userweb">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521/servicename"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="testuser"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="testpass"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

what is going wrong?

## update

```
java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : [PersistenceUnit: userweb] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory. Please see server.log for more details.
```

getting above error too.

Comment: Are you sure you are using this config in your deployed application? The config contains port 1521, while your errormessage says: "Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect."

Comment: Also try to connect to the database using a client to see if it can be connected properly.

Comment: I will paste the complete exception log

Comment: I am using the port 1521 only, that is the oracle default.

Comment: You are trying to configure an Oracle connection, but your app is using "derby" (see stacktrace) and trying to connect on port 1527 (derby default).

Comment: I just checked and glassfish server contains connection pool for derby, how can I configure glassfish to use oracle?

Comment: It is not this easy. You would need to heavily update your original question with information about your current glassfish config regarding db + some info about how your application picks up the DB reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89771/discussion-between-eatsleepcode-and-gergely-bacso).

Comment: @GergelyBacso I just configure peristence.xml for db connection and at glassfish I tried to configure oracle datasource but libraries are not present in classpasth. I don't know which all libraries are needed, do you have any idea.

Comment: Your application contains the Oracle connection params (plus the required Oracle libraries I assume). Somebody also added the Derby connection params to your glassfish server, likely with the derby drivers. This needs to be sorted out, but that required the info I mentioned above.

Comment: @GergelyBacso I don't know much about glassfish, but I will try to give you some info, what configurations do you want to know?

Comment: The DB configurations.

Comment: @GergelyBacso sorry but Its a company database I can not give you db configurations. If you can give input about how to configure datasource and adding oracle jar to glassfish server will be helpful.

Comment: Without knowing how your server configured (not the actual IP and password but the way it was setup) it is close to impossible to give you advice on that. Anyway, read this one, it might help: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2432/gkyan.html

Comment: @GergelyBacso I configured the datasource and able to ping it from glassfish admin console. Now getting this exception `Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getSchema()Ljava/lang/String;` do you know any reason for this?

Comment: @GergelyBacso I am using ojdbc6.jar in glassfish server domain and in my applications lib.

Comment: My best guess is that you have another oracle driver (probably ojdbc14.jar) on your classpath. Either in glassfish lib, or among the dependencies of your application). Please check both.